# Magento 2 redirect back with message from controller, redirecting working fine but error message not showing

Tags: redirect, magento2.4.1, success-message

Messages do not appear after redirection. Tried many solutions but no luck. Here is the code I tried. I have created a fronted form with custom routing with URL params.

```
public function execute(){
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        try{
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Redirection Sucessful.'));
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());            
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

And

```
public function execute(){
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try{
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Redirection Sucessful.'));
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());            
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

in `sulkar_sktok_form.xml` file into

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">            
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

use setPath instead of setUrl.
$resultRedirect->setPath($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

Comment: Still messages do not appear after redirection.